# python pandas get info about all the columns (> 900 columns)

Tags: python

I have a txt file with more than 900 columns.  I would like to look at the datatypes and columnames, but with df.dtypes I don't get everything, just a fraction.  Can I increase this?  Is this a setting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried saving dtypes as an object?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: ```your_object = df.dtypes```

Comment: and then display it whatever way. with ```head()``` or other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it depends on the environment where you run you commands. But I hope it might be more universal to do it in a loop.

Maybe not the most elegant option though, but try this:

```
types = df.dtypes

for index in types.index:
    print(index, types[index])
```